# Keyboard does not work for first few seconds

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, keyboard

I notice that my keyboard does not work for first few seconds while I boot into ubuntu or open after suspension. After a few seconds it works completely fine. I get stuck in the login page for a few seconds as I am unable to enter anything using my keyboard. I use a HP pavilion 15 series laptop with ubuntu 20.04.3 dual booted along with windows.

PS: Its not the slow keys that's creating this issue

Has anyone encountered similar issues? and knows a solution?

Comment: What issue? Your question is very unclear. You say the keyboard has an issue and then you say it is not the keyboard.

Comment: A lot of modern notebooks have the keyboard on the USB bus. If the USB devices require a few seconds to initialise after the machine starts up, this would explain the lag. If you [edit] your question to include the terminal output of `sudo lsusb`, it may be possible to verify this.

Comment: To be more clear, it does not work only for first few seconds after booting or suspending. After that it works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to fix this bug go to your `/etc/default/grub` and add `i8042.nopnp=1 i8042.dumbkbd=1`.

1. Open `/etc/default/grub`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Change the following line from:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   to:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nopnp=1 i8042.dumbkbd=1"
   ```
3. Save the changes made to GRUB (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>).
4. Then open a terminal and run the following:

   ```
   sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   ```
5. Restart and your keyboard lag should be fixed.

Comment: This worked perfectly on my HP Spectre x360 running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Thank you!

Comment: this worked on HP running ubuntu 22.04 LTS thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check this topic https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1916314

https://github.com/berzoidberg/i8042-spectre-dkms

I have same issue on my HP Spectre and here is what i did:

```
git clone https://github.com/berzoidberg/i8042-spectre-dkms
sudo cp -R i8042-spectre-dkms /usr/src/i8042-spectre-1.0
sudo dkms add -m i8042-spectre -v 1.0
sudo dkms build -m i8042-spectre -v 1.0
sudo dkms install -m i8042-spectre -v 1.0
echo blacklist i8042 | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Comment: I tried this but still doesn't solve the problem. Is there anything else that has to be done after these 6 commands? Or just close the terminal?